# Bash find files and loop contents

Tags: bash

Taking from this repo [@andrew8088/dotfiles/blob/main/install/bootstrap.sh](https://github.com/andrew8088/dotfiles/blob/main/install/bootstrap.sh) I'm trying to use the existing code there to loop my MacOS $DOTFILES repo to find `links.prop` files, read the contents of the file and run the appropriate symlink.

The problem is when I run the `bash install/boostrap.sh` with the below snippet I don't get the expected results.

```
install_dotfiles () {
  info 'installing dotfiles'

  local overwrite_all=false backup_all=false skip_all=false

  find -H "$DOTFILES" -maxdepth 2 -name 'links.prop' -not -path '*.git*' | while read linkfile
  do
    echo $linkfile
    cat "$linkfile" | while read line
    do
        echo $line;
        local src dst dir
        src=$(eval echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 1)
        dst=$(eval echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 2)
        dir=$(dirname $dst)

        mkdir -p "$dir"
        link_file "$src" "$dst"
    done
  done
}
```

*output*

```
  [ .. ] installing dotfiles
/Users/username/github/dotfiles/zsh/links.prop
/Users/username/github/dotfiles/git/links.prop
  [ OK ] /Users/douglasbeaumont/.env.sh file already exists, skipping

  [ OK ] All installed!
```

It finds the files fine but won't read the contents.

`zsh/links.prop` has the line `$DOTFILES/zsh/rc.zsh=$HOME/.zshrc`.

Comment: Does it only have that line, or is there other stuff? Is that line properly terminated with a newline?

Comment: The typical workaround if you can't guarantee a terminating newline is `while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]] ; do...`

Comment: Just singular line in each file.

Eg: `$DOTFILES/zsh/rc.zsh=$HOME/.zshrc`

Comment: Can you add "cat "$linkfile"' before the loop (and maybe comment out the loop)?

Comment: See [BashFAQ/001 - My text files are broken! They lack their final newlines!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#My_text_files_are_broken.21__They_lack_their_final_newlines.21).

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this sample script:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf '%s' 'test data' > testfile
while read -r line ; do
  echo "$line"
done < testfile
```

It prints nothing, but if you `cat testfile` it's clearly populated. What gives?

The problem here is that `read` exits with a non-zero status if it encounters end-of-file before a newline, which causes the while loop to terminate. If your file only has a single line and it's not newline-terminated, like `testfile` above, then it will look like the contents aren't being read but that's not actually the case.

If you can't guarantee every line is newline-terminated, then there is a workaround:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf '%s' 'test data' > testfile
while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]] ; do
  echo "$line"
done < testfile
```

The unterminated line will still cause `read` to exit non-zero, but because `line` is still populated you can follow that up with a check that there's something in it and process it before exiting the loop.